# Alternatives to sleep when checking if Netty server is up?

Tags: java, netty, resteasy

I am starting Netty with a rest interface. I get this exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:102)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.ping(Unknown Source)
    at com.openet.atf.agent.proxy.SlaveRemoteProxy.ping(SlaveRemoteProxy.java:41)
    at com.openet.atf.agent.manage.Master.startSlaves(Master.java:86)
    at com.openet.acceptance.runner.AcceptanceRunner.main(AcceptanceRunner.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://ovm1:8889 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I prevented this from happening by doing a `Thread.sleep(5000);`. I am looking for a better alternative to `sleep`. Sleep always assumes that the length of time is 5 seconds.

Comment: "Sleep always assumes that the length of time is 5 seconds" - Is that good or bad regarding your requirements? Have you considered Quartz Scheduler or ScheduledExecutorService?

Comment: Are you connecting to a local (as in in-app) REST service and you want to wait until it is up and running before continuing, or are you attempting to connect to an external application which may or may not be running? Or have I got the question completely wrong?

Comment: I don't want to sleep for 5 seconds if it comes up in 4 seconds, and if it takes 10 seconds to come up then 5 seconds is not long enough. Using a timeout is not really a robust way to check if it it is up. It would be better to poll something. I am connecting to a netty REST service I have started on a remote node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sleep until the connection is established.

```
 boolean up = false;
 while (!up) {
     try {
         // Try to connect
         up = true;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A common approach used in situations where success could be any time in the future is the [*back off pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-off_pattern), typically implemented by doubling the wait time every iteration.

Something like this:

```
long wait = 50; // ms
boolean connected;
while (!connected) {
    Thread.sleep(wait);
    connected = <code to check connection>
    wait *= 2;
}
```